# Array subtraction in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have two arrays and I want a resulting array that's the vector difference.

A1:A10 and B1:B10 have numeric values, and I want {A1:A10}-{B1:B10}, but that just gives me A1-B1, not the full array. Is there a subtraction operator for arrays?

Example Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rjh_mkpZdz7LX4V0obxEmfRLdZ2CoTIjdpxVLHYBD5s/edit#gid=0

I want the result in D1 without the extra column C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ArrayFormula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A10-B1:B10)
```

or shorter Index:

```
=INDEX(A1:A10-B1:B10)
```

or longer Query:

```
=QUERY(A1:B10, "select A-B label A-B''", 0)
```